Should I relocate the Raphigaster that tries to winter in my house
In mid October a shieldbug entered my house. After 3 days, it found a very small hole inside one of the veneers under my bedroom window. It stayed there for days, so I did a quick search and was sure it would like to try and hibernate (I'm unsure if this is the correct term) there.
Temperature's outside have only recently (15 days or so) hit winterly levels. I have started to turn on more heating. My house has pretty high temperature fluctuations, especially in the bedroom area.
Yesterday the bug emerged from the hole, waited 2 inches from the entry for an hour or so, then went in again. It emerged again today and is still sitting outside of the hole.
I'm afraid the fluctuations are confusing it.
Can someone explain to me if Raphigaster needs constant "sleep" to winter and would it be better to leave it alone and figure something out by itself or should I place it outside, even though temperatures are below freezing?

You might want to get a positive ID on it, not all shield bugs are Raphigaster genus and some are invasive pests, such as the Brown Marmorated Stink Bug.

@bob1I'm 90% percent sure it's Rhaphigaster nebulosa but will try to get a picture if it emerges again; the bug has reentered its home.

@bob1 my initial thought went straight to H. halys, too. Based on OP's name (German), R nebulosa is an option (the native) , but so is H. halys (invaded as of 2011). Both are similarly colored, and both may find their way inside. Differentiatibg between them would be possible, but I'm not sure IDing to species here necessarily changes OP's question or a likely answer (though possibly, so Wottensprels please take photo if possible)
